# Wallet is encrypted and currently locked. How can I get it decrypted (unlocked) - I have my password!

Tags: wallet

I have run into the problem of my wallet being encrypted and currently locked. I am using [Bitcoin-Qt](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin-Qt). I have my password to unlock it, but I can't find an area in the interface to unlock the wallet.

Where do I enter my password to unlock?

Answer (score 2):

You will be asked for your password when you want to send coins.

Alternatively, you can unlock your wallet for a period of time using the walletpassphrase command in the console.

Answer (score 0):

CLICK: Help
CLICK: Debug Window
CLICK: Console

Input the following command-line: walletpassphrase  9999999 true
 with the Password you created to Encrypt your Qt Wallet>.  Hit Enter after you type this phrase.

After you close the Console-Your the lock in the bottom bar will unlock (though you may have to look carefully to see the change.  If you hover your cursor over the lock you should see the phrase: "Qt Wallet is now ENCRYPTED AND UN-LOCKED- for block minting only."    The warning about your client being unable to mint should disappear also.